# When to use AttachedProperties in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, wpf-controls, attached-properties

Here are my doubts,

1. **When to use** AttachedProperties in wpf
2. Should I use AttachedProperties **only with ContentControls** (like Panels) where are there one or more children
3. What is the **use of AttachedProperties**
4. Can I use AttachedProperties for **extending properties** of a control, i.e., properties that don't exists but I would like to add to the control without modifying the object hierarchy of that control

P.S.: I have already read the MSDN link on AttachedProperties, still I would like to hear the best from the stackoverflow users

Thanks

Comment: This question is very general, just search for introductory information about AttachedProperties and it will probably be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these posts that are related:

[What are the various uses of Attached Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195638/what-are-the-various-uses-of-attached-properties)

[How exactly do Attached Properties work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173494/how-exactly-do-attached-properties-work-in-wpf)

[What's the difference between a dependency property and an attached property in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240699/whats-the-difference-between-a-dependency-property-and-an-attached-property-in-w)